# How to correctly make jQuery One Page Nav applicable on a scrollable div?

Tags: jquery

I modified a known jQuery plugin called [One Page Nav](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) in order to make it applicable on a scrollable `div` rather than an entire webpage. My modified version is working correctly until browser resizing.

Most of my modifications are changing the referenced target from `document` to the scrollable `div`. Here is my [modified version on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IanY/cL7qx4o9/1/).

To reproduce the issues, clicking on one or two nav items (and let the scrolling animation run) first, and then resize your browser. After browser resizing, I'm seeing two issues:

- Clicking on a nav item to trigger the scrolling animation. When the scrolling animation finishes, the "current" indicator suddenly changes to another nav item.
- When scrolling the content manually, the "current" indicator changes to wrong nav items.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from `getPositions`. When retrieving the top position of each section, it does not take into account the current scroll position. This is why, in [your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IanY/cL7qx4o9/1/), the bug occurs only if the window is resized when the content is already scrolled (not at the top). [This modified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/cL7qx4o9/3/) logs to the console the section positions obtained in `getPositions`. If you scroll to the bottom and resize the window, you will see that some of these positions have a negative value.

Here is the corrected version, which uses an expression similar to the one found in the `scrollTo` method. You can see the code at work in **[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/oumjv9hh/)**.

```
getPositions: function() {
    var self = this;
    var linkHref;
    var topPos;
    var $target;
    var contentScrollTop = $('#content').scrollTop(); // Correction for scroll position

    self.$nav.each(function() {
        linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
        $target = $('#' + linkHref);

        if ($target.length) {
            topPos = contentScrollTop + $target.position().top; // Correct value
            self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos);
        }
    });
},
```